# Problem that is not well-posed

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm currently self-studying partial differential equations using the book: An Introduction to Partial Differential Equations with MATLAB.

On one of the chapter exercises, I'm faced with the question of showing that this problem below is not well-posed.

For the Laplace Equation $\\u_{xx}$ + $\\u_{yy} = 0$ with conditions $\\u_{x}(0,y)=$$\\u_{x}(1,y)=$$\\u_{y}(x,0)=$$\\u_{y}(x,2)=0,  0$$\leq x\leq1, 0\leq y\leq2$

Why is the problem not well-posed?

My guess is that the initial condition for u is not provided for, is that correct?

P.S: I have only barely started on linear PDEs (the definitions etc) but not not solving techniques yet, so I would like to kindly request that the answer be given as simple as possible. Thank you.

Comment: There is no uniqueness: All constant functions solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that!